# Using a multi-field form with a single field in ag-grid

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I'm evaluating ag-grid as a solution in our project.  My users like the simplicity of an 'excel' type solution.  My issue is, when entering a new record into the grid, there are often times we want to enter more info to create the record beyond what's displayed in ag-grid.

For example, say you have a column called 'Contact' which displays a contact's name in the grid.  When we create a new contact record we also want to record some other fields about the contact such as 'phone', 'email', 'address', etc.  But, I don't want these fields shown in the grid.

So what I was thinking is that it would be great if we click into a dropdown cell we could include a 'new' button or link which would launch a dialog or similar with the new contact form inside of it.  The user would enter the info for the new contact and once they submit the form it closes the dialog and the dropdown in ag-grid is updated to pick the newly created contact.

I'll be using ag-grid with react.

Is something like this possible?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same question but never found an answer. Ended up using [react data grid](https://adazzle.github.io/react-data-grid/)